# Linux + Windows. Почему grub слетает через каждые 2-3 месяца?

Tags: linux, windows, grub

Надоело уже чинить. Думаю и о зловещей Microsoft, и о своей глупости, и много ещё о чём, а толку? Кто-то сталкивался с таким? примерно раз в 2-3 месяца ломается Grub, пишет "normal.mod not found", после чего несусь ставить груб с флешки заново. Arch Linux у меня. Возможно, такое из-за неправильного отключения виндовс, но точно не могу отловить причину.

Comment: Так как тут сказано делали? https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dual_boot_with_Windows и https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_boot_process

Comment: Тоже подзадолбало (было с периодичностью в 3-4 дня), посто снёс всё и поставил уже Linux как основную и единственную)